# Memory leak when parse JSON string using SBJSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, sbjson

I am using following code to parse JSON and getting memory leak (100%) on line number 2. I don't know what is the problem, can someone help me ?

```
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [response JSONValue]; (100% leak)

    NSString *tockenString = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"Token"];
    NSString *userIDString = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"ID"];
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're over-releasing stuff.

Comment: edited my question but still no luck.

Comment: Are you using the latest release of SBJSON from github? Have you tried using an alternative JSON parser like KSJSON? Have you used Instruments to determine which code path causes the leak?

Comment: I am using latest release of SBJSON. I did not use KSJSON before.

Comment: Either you've got a bogus copy of SBJSON or you're misinterpreting the diagnostics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Go to SBJsonParser.m function scanRestOfString and change the line

from

```
        *o = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes:(char*)c length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

to

```
        *o = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes:(char*)c length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

SBJsonParser has a like in scanRestOfString/NSMutableString. I reported the bug as well. Thank you all.

Comment: Seems odd that you would happen upon a bug in such a well-used piece of code.

Comment: Even i found it odd. But when i implemented the changes, i didn’t get any leak from instrument analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Remove those 2 autoreleases. They overrelease the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem but it turned out the leak was actually higher in the chain of methods, but Instruments was (mistakenly) pointing to this line. Look at the methods that store the results retrieved from this code.